# Value of select box as dynamic date

Tags: javascript, date, drop-down-menu

How can I set the value of a `select box` with JS to current day and selected period in the past, for example, for today's date `2018-01-09` and the selected date 30 days ago `2017-12-10` the option value should be `2018-01-03,2018-01-09`. The same must apply for each 7, 14, 30, 90 and 365 days. So far I have tried this...

```
setTimeout(function () {
  var today = new Date()
  var last7 = new Date().setDate(today.getDate()-7)
  var last14 = new Date().setDate(today.getDate()-14)
  var last30 = new Date().setDate(today.getDate()-30)
  var last90 = new Date().setDate(today.getDate()-90)
  var last365 = new Date().setDate(today.getDate()-365)

  $('#DateSelector').val('30').trigger("change");
  }, 1000);
```

Yet, I cannot find a way use these variables in the `option` value.

```
<select name="DateSelector" id="DateSelector" onchange="overviewDates();">
   <option value="">Last 7 Days</option>
   <option value="">Last 14 Days</option>
   <option value="">Last 30 Days</option>
   <option value="">Last 90 Days</option>
   <option value="">Last 365 Days</option>
</select>
```

Comment: *setDate* returns the new [*time value*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-time-values-and-time-range), not a Date object. So each of your variables (*last7*, *last14*, etc.) is a number, not a Date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you're using *setTimeout*, just call the function once the element is in the page. I've used the window's load event, but there are other ways.

*setDate* returns a time value, where you want a formatted date string so you need to modify that part of your code. Then you need to assign the new values to the option elements, so:

```js
// Set select values
function setSelectValues(id) {
  var sel = document.getElementById(id);
  if (!sel) return;
  // Array of intervals to set
  Array.from(sel.options).forEach(function(opt) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - opt.value);
    opt.value = formatYMD(d);
  });
}

// Helper to format the date
function formatYMD(date) {
  return date.getFullYear() + '-' + 
    ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
    ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
}

// Run updater
window.onload = function(){setSelectValues('DateSelector')};
```

```html
<select name="DateSelector" id="DateSelector" onchange="console.log(this.value)">
   <option value="7" selected>Last 7 Days</option>
   <option value="14">Last 14 Days</option>
   <option value="30">Last 30 Days</option>
   <option value="90">Last 90 Days</option>
   <option value="365">Last 365 Days</option>
</select>
```

You should also set one of the options as selected (typically the first).

Comment: Cheers @RobG, this should fit into my current code. The `setTimeout` could of most likely been removed for this question but is needed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Add the value to select and get that from the function, then substract this.

```js
function overviewDates(e) {
 var s = e.target,
     selected = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value,
     d = new Date(),
     cur = d.setDate(d.getDate() - selected);
     
     t.innerHTML = `${selected} days ago was: ${d.toLocaleString()}`
 }
 
 var s = document.getElementById("DateSelector").addEventListener("click", overviewDates);
```

```html
<select name="DateSelector" id="DateSelector"
   <option value="7">Last 7 Days</option>
   <option value="14">Last 14 Days</option>
   <option value="30">Last 30 Days</option>
   <option value="90">Last 90 Days</option>
   <option value="365">Last 365 Days</option>
</select>

<h1 id="t"></h1>
```

Comment: The OP wants to insert the date in format YYYY-MM-DD into the option value, not the numbers 7, 14, etc.

Comment: Thanks, @RobG, this is correct. The select box option is changing the URL of an API to pull data by specific date. The value must be updated to appear as `2018-01-03,2018-01-09`. I just cannot find a way to include a variable in a `value` of an `option` when the `script` is external. I will update my question so you can see the full picture. Maybe I am thinking of this backward.